# R: Writing reactive output to an excel file?

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I am creating a method in R that takes in 4 values from a survey and then saves them to local variables and places them in a matrix, it then writes that matrix to an excel file. Pretty simple concept, however since the input is reactive.. if more than one survey is entered then it just overwrites the previous survey.. so now I need a counter variable. Here is some clips of the code.

(In the server class)

```
  surveyFinish <- eventReactive(input$click2,{``
  state = input$UState
  happiness = input$UHap
  work = input$UWork
  env = input$UEnv
  surveyans <- paste(state, happiness, work, env, sep=" ")

  newMat = matrix(
    c(state, env, work, happiness),
    nrow = 1,
    ncol = 4,
    byrow = TRUE)

  writeWorksheetToFile("StateSurvey.xlsx", newMat, "SomeOtherSheet", z, 1, header = FALSE)
  write.table(newMat, "SurveyTab.txt", sep="\t")



  return()
})

 output$youSaid<- renderDataTable({
  surveyFinish()
})
```

(In the UI)

```
tabPanel("Survey",
                  textInput("UState", label = h2("Your State"), 
                            value = "State name"),
                  numericInput("UHap", label = h2("Your Happiness"), 
                            value = "Enter a number from 1-10", min = 1, max = 10),
                  numericInput("UEnv", label = h2("Your Environment"), 
                               value = "Enter a number from 1-10", min = 1, max = 10),
                  numericInput("UWork", label = h2("Your Workload"), 
                               value = "Enter a number from 1-10", min = 1, max = 10),
                  actionButton("click2", "Finish Survey!"),

                  tableOutput("youSaid")


         ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Each session of shiny is independent therefore you may need a global variable that shared across all the session. Global variable can be defined in global.R within same folder with server.R and ui.R. More reference [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html)

Or alternative you just write the survey results in separate txt file using the timestamp they submitted and read all at once later when the survey finish and write the final result to excel file then.